# build issue with gradle 4.4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I upgraded my project with gradle 4.4 and I get the following error:

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Authentication required
```

I'm behind a corporate proxy but I don't have any problem with gradle 4.1.

What happens please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned there's issues with bintray today.  One suggestion I've seen in meantime is to put google and maven before jcenter in your list of repos.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```